# How to check if any required tags are blank Azure Policy

Tags: json, azure, tags, azure-policy

I am trying to create an azure policy that audits vms. Conditions I want to satisfy is that the vm has all of the tags specified by parameter and that all of those corresponding tags contain a value. The first condition I have working with below. However for determining if they are blank or not is a bit more challenging as looks like you can not use current() in the field key.

```json
{
  "parameters": {
    "requiredTags": {
      "type": "Array",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Required Tags",
        "description": "The list of tags that should exist on the virtual machine"
      }
    }
  },
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allof": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Compute/VirtualMachines"
        },
        {
          "count": {
            "value": "[parameters('requiredTags')]",
            "where": {
              "field": "tags",
              "containsKey": "[current()]"
            }
          },
          "notEquals": "[length(parameters('requiredTags'))]"
        },
        {
          "count": {
            "value": "[parameters('requiredTags')]",
            "where": {
              "field": "[concat('tags[', current(), ']')]",
              "notEquals": ""
            }
          },
          "notEquals": "[length(parameters('requiredTags'))]"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "audit"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Am aware I can do via cli, powershell and graph api but prefer if I can add as a policy so it is consistently audited.

Answer (score 1):

This was very tricky to say at least, and it seems like no such policy exists out there. Nevertheless, I believe that the 2 options below will do the trick - at least it did so when I tested it.

Option 1:

```
  {
    "not": {
      "value": "[contains(string(field('tags')), '\"\"')]",
      "equals": true
    }
  }
```

Option 2:

```
  {
    "value": "[indexOf(string(field('tags')), '\"\"')]",
    "greaterOrEquals": 0
  }
```

**Description:**
Option 1:
Use `contains` to check wheather an object contains a key or a string contains a substring.
The `container` contains nested parameters.
`string` converts the specified value to a string. In this case, the specified value is the `field = tags`, which are objects, not an array. In this case, the specified value is the field = tags, which are `objects`, not an `array`.
Example of 2 tags, "tagnumber1" with the value "value1" and "tagnumber2" with an empty value:
`"{\"tagnumber1\":\"value1\",\"tagnumber2\":\"\"}"`
Note that the empty value is `\"\"` - this is our `itemToFind`.

Option 2:
Use the `indexOf` to return the first position of a value within a string.
The `stringToSearch` contains nested parameters.
The `stringToFind` is empty.
`string` converts the specified value to a string. In this case, the specified value is the `field = tags`, which are `objects`, not an `array`.
Example of 2 tags, "tagnumber1" with the value "value1" and "tagnumber2" with an empty value:
`"{\"tagnumber1\":\"value1\",\"tagnumber2\":\"\"}"`
Note that the empty value is `\"\"`.
Therefore, we must search for that `\"\"` as this represents the empty value in the object.
The index is zero-based. If the item is not found, -1 is returned. An integer represents the first index of the item, so by looking at `"greaterOrEquals": 0` it will only return that is the item is found - meaning a tag value is empty.

Links:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure#fields
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-expressions#escape-characters
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/virtualmachines?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template#resource-format-1

Comment: This is a great answer. But when the policy fails, the compliance details doesn't output what tags were missing, but rather that the count isn't matching. 

`Reason for non-compliance: Number of matching array members must be equal to the target value.`, `Number of matching array members: 0`, and `Target value: "2"`

How can we adjust this so it can output which one(s) of the `requiredTags` were missing?

Comment: @flyte I believe that is not possible using the `value count` or any array for that matter. Unfortunately.

Comment: ..hrm, that's unfortunate. So then I suspect the only way really understand what tags are missing is if we have individual policies for each tag, or "hard code" the tag names within a single policy that performs an "allof" check on them. Then know what was missing.. (?)

Comment: Just enforce "deny" instead of audit. Then people cannot do tags without a value. If you have a few tags and they will not change, the best way is just to hardcode it as you say.